# Send Instant Message in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

I am New to iphone. Currently I am using Mac os 3.2, By using this version can i send Instant message programmatically? Because,I got an error like undelared MFMessageViewController.

What can I do? If it possible,then send sample code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi you mean you want to send SMS right?

Answer (score 1):

MFMessage service was made public for the iOS 4.0 and later.So if you want to integrate SMS facility then you will have to upgrade your XCode SDK 3.2(& iO.S >= 4.0).

You can implement SMS functionality by following the sample code provided by Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html

Cheers
Aditya

Comment: is not possible to send sms below 3.2

Comment: See you need minimum iOS version 4.0.The Xcode version has to be 3.2 or later.